# Windows 8.1 App Certification fails for Platform appropriate files

Tags: dll, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit, cpu-architecture, appxmanifest

My Windows Store App works for all architectures (x86, x64, arm) and is published on the Store. But when building App Package (right-click on project, Store, Create App Package) Windows App Certification Kit 3.1 for Windows 8.1 passed all the tests except for **Platform appropriate files** test:

- Error Found: The platform appropriate files test detected the following errors:

  - File fmodexMetroL64.dll is designed only for x64 processor type; AppX manifest declares 'ProcessorArchitecture' as x86.
  - File fmodexMetroLarm.dll is designed only for arm processor type; AppX manifest declares 'ProcessorArchitecture' as x86.
  - File fmodexMetro64.dll is designed only for x64 processor type; AppX manifest declares 'ProcessorArchitecture' as x86.
  - File fmodexMetroarm.dll is designed only for arm processor type; AppX manifest declares 'ProcessorArchitecture' as x86.
- How to fix:  Ensure that binary file architecture is compatible with the ProcessorArchitecture attribute specified within the AppX manifest. 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=294935

The issue here is I have .dll files for each architecture and they get added for any architecture build, no matter what I try. I haven't found how to tell Visual Studio some .dll should only be included for a specific architecture build and not others.

My AppX manifest doesn't declare any file at all and doesn't declare any 'ProcessorArchitecture' at all.

My current **ugly** solution, each time I want to build:

1. I remove the .dll from the project for incorrect architectures
2. I build for a single architecture only
3. I re-insert the previously removed .dll to the project

I'd like to find a way to avoid this pain.

Comment: Do you build them separately(different architectures)?

Comment: @crea7or Right-click on the Project -> Store -> Build App Package. It built all three packages in folder AppPackage in one go.

Comment: "Neutral" is unchecked?

Comment: @crea7or where is it? *edit* oh yes, it is unchecked

Comment: The IDE doesn't cater well to this scenario.  I think you can make it work by editing the project file by hand and adding a Conditional that checks the Platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:
Open menu `Project`, then `Project properties`. Tab `Build` and set different `Output path` values(paths) for the different `Platform target`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this solution helped for me:

Open your project, and select the Solution,Then open menu Project and select Properties.

- Inside the Property Pages go to -> Configuration Properties.

On this page you can set the Platform targets.